# Is it safe/feasible to treat uniqueidentifier as string rather than System.Guid for comparison purposes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, compare, uniqueidentifier

When working with `uniqueidentifier` from the database. Most of the time I just need it for comparison purposes in LINQ queries, and as value of `HyperLink`'s `NavigateUrl` and similar situations. So, is it safe/feasible to treat `uniqueidentifier` as string rather than `System.Guid` for comparison purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it requires more careful coding than comparing Guids.

Code that uses `Guid` for comparison is easier to get correct as there is exactly one representation of unique `Guid` value in that form.

String representation is way more flexible (i.e. case, dashes) so you may need to either normalize values first (i.e. lower-case and remove all non-alphanumeric characters), or have custom comparator (i.e. one that only compares alphanumeric characters and ignores case).

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is even a problem with the ordering of the "groups" of digits (Oracle does it differently)